# Adding package to Ironpython In Visual studio

Tags: python, wpf, visual-studio, ironpython

I wrote a python code which uses the following line:

```
def score(name,option):

    from urllib.request import urlopen
    import numpy as np

    url = urlopen('.....')
```

The code works when I run it using Pycharm and more.

However, I had like to use the following function inside Wpf that I build in visual studio and I get the following exception:

```
ImportError: No module named request
```

From what I understand I should add the package to Ironpython.

How can I add it to my visual studio project?

Thank you.